# How to check AngularJs form field on Cancel button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a Cancel button on a form. When a user clicks on the Cancel button I have three scenarios.

1. If the user has entered values in any field and, without saving, clicks on the cancel button I am alerting "all data will be lost" and redirecting it to home page
2. If the user has not entered any values in form fields and clicks on cancel I don't want to display the message "all the data will be lost". It will be a different message and redirect it to home because he did not enter any information, so I want to display a different message.
3. Once form is saved and now we are in edit Mode without changing any
   existing     values how to implement second scenario, No value is
   changed if user clicks on cancel don't want to display the message
   "all the data will be lost".

   How to check the second scenario if no values were entered in the
   form fields and on handleCancel display a different message?

   How to check third scenario in edit Mode if existing values are not changed then click on      cancel behavior should be similar to second scenario ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="processOwnerRes" 
                ng-model="challengesDTO.challengeResponseWrk"
                name="processOwnerRes" readonly="readonly" > 
    </div>

 <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="handleCancel()">Cancel</button>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                ng-disabled="processChallengeForm.$invalid"  
                ng-class="{disableSaveCls:processChallengeForm.$invalid}" 
                ng-click="submit()" >Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.handleCancel = function () {
    if($rootScope.status !== 'view') {
        $scope.messageText = $rootScope.alertMessages['common.cancelConfirmMessage'];
        $scope.confirmationWin.open().center();
        $scope.yesCallback = $scope.cancelPRT;
    } else { $scope.redirectToProcessScreen(); }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the properties **$pristine** or **$dirty** to check if the user has already interacted with the form.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Something like this:

```
$scope.handleCancel = function () {
    if($rootScope.status !== 'view') {
          if($scope.processChallengeForm.$dirty){
               $scope.messageText = $rootScope.alertMessages['common.cancelConfirmMessage'];
               $scope.confirmationWin.open().center();
               $scope.yesCallback = $scope.cancelPRT;
          }
    } else { $scope.redirectToProcessScreen(); }
};
```

Comment: one issue just noticed if you entered value and then remove field value to blank its not working , is it  because i interacted with the field and later removed the value ?

Comment: @aftab yes. Any interaction marks the form as `$dirty`.

Comment: Yes. The dirty property is set to true when the user interacts with the input, but even if the value of the input returns to its original value, the dirty property still true.

Comment: is there any other approach that can resolve this issue ?